# How to get json data?

Tags: php, json

I have two Json files. I've got a problem to get the data from the second Json depending on the first Json.

I want to display "changePercent" key of the second Json depending of "short" key from the first Json.

"symbol" has to match with "short"

This is for a php file. I am trying to retrieve live data.

First Json:

```
[
{"long":"Microsoft","short":"MSFT"},
{"long":"Facebook","short":"FB"},
{"long":"Frankfurt Dax Index","short":"DAX30"}
]
```

Second Json:

```
{
"AAPL":{"quote":{"symbol":"AAPL","changePercent":0.04}},
"FB":{"quote":{"symbol":"FB","changePercent":0.03}} 
}
```

My code:

```
$json1 = $CCWE->feed($CCWE->config->feeds->coincap->front);
$json2 = file_get_contents('json2url');
$obj = json_decode($json2); 

if ( in_array($json1->short , array('AAPL','MSFT'), true ) ) {                                   
echo $obj->{$json1->short}->changePercent;                                   
}
```

I expected to get changePercent

Comment: Is `$json1` already decoded? Is it an array like you depicted in the top of your question? If so, then `$json->short` should give an error. Do you get any error?

Comment: Yes it is already decoded. It doesn't display any thing

Comment: I am confused. You seem to want to pick the "short" value in `$json1`, and then find it in `$json2`, but the "short" value is "Facebook", while `$json2` has "FB". Obviously that does not match. But `$json1` has "FB" too in the "long" property. Are you sure you need "short" for this?

Comment: I already have the short value in json1. And yes, i made a mistake in my question, i inverted short and long but this is only in the question

Comment: `$json1` would be an array.  You need to iterate through each array row, or specify an individual row that you want to check.

Comment: Yes $json1 is an array

Comment: @user3492770 Does your stock application need to display the long name (e.g. "Microsoft", "Apple") or only short names (e.g. "MSFT", "AAPL")?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the first json.

```
$json2 = file_get_contents('json2url');

/**
 * Explanation:
 * passing `true` to json_decode will result in an array instead of an object.
 */
foreach ( json_decode($json2, true) as $short=>$data )
{

    if ( in_array($short, ['AAPL', 'MSFT']) ) {
        echo $short . " changed: " . $data['quote']['changePercent'] . "<br>\n";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the JSON data is as you indicate then you should get an error on `$json-short`, since `$json1` is an array, and you can only do `->` on objects.

It seems like you want to find corresponding keys, and get the percentage when there is a match. You could do that as follows.

```
foreach($json1 as $obj1)  {
    if (isset($obj->{$obj1->short})) {
        echo $obj1->short . "\n";
        echo $obj->{$obj1->short}->quote->changePercent . "\n";
    }
}
```